# A workaround for SSL on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Got an app running great on Heroku, only issue is that their custom-domain SSL solution is way expensive (http://docs.heroku.com/ssl), leaving piggybacking of their *.heroku.com as an only viable option.  The good thing is that my app only requires SSL for a couple of pages (for ordering).  Right now, I use "ssl_required" in my controller for those couple actions.  Any idea on how to create a before_filter that would bump the user to https://myapp.heroku.com just for those two actions and redirect to http://www.myapp.com for anything else?  Ugly ugly, but seems like the best way to go for now.

Comment: Did you end up hacking _SSL Requirement_, like Wojtek suggested?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could hack/monkey-patch:
*SSL Requirement* plugin (github.com/rails/ssl_requirement), so that it redirected to different hosts.

BTW if you plan to host multiple applications, they can share one multi-domain certificate (and one pricey SSL Addon). Here's more detailed description: [http://wojciech.oxos.pl/post/277669886/save-on-herokus-custom-ssl-addons](http://wojtek.oxos.pl/post/277669886/save-on-herokus-custom-ssl-addons)